# cygwin g++ compiling with Python.h (duplicated definition of __BSD_VISIBLE)

Tags: python, c++

I am encountering with this issue with latest cygwin g++-5.4.0 and python3.4. Following simple code exposes this issue:

```
#include <string>
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
//#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling with " g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 test.c -o test `python3-config --includes`", I got following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h:8:0,
                 from test.c:2:
/usr/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h:1440:0: warning: "__BSD_VISIBLE" redefined
 #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/sys/config.h:5:0,
                 from /usr/include/_ansi.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/wchar.h:4,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/string:40,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/include/sys/features.h:250:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define __BSD_VISIBLE  0
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.4m/pyport.h:335:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h:50,
                 from test.c:2:
/usr/include/sys/time.h:104:34: error: 'u_int' has not been declared bintime_mul(struct bintime *_bt, u_int _x)
```

One tricky thing is that if I include  after "Python.h". Compiling goes through. I don't see this issue on linux/Mac OS.

I don't see this is a valid solution. Since with more complicated code, I run into a segment default at very beginning of the program (before entering main function).

Answer (score 2):

Modify the file `/usr/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h`, replacing

```
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
```

with

```
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 0
```